# How to see if one variable increases as much as another but not with correlation?

Tags: r, correlation

I want to know if one variable increases as much as another. I know you can use correlation to see if one increases, so does the other, but this doesn't show that they're increasing at the same rate. Also I'm doing this in R.

Comment: You can use a log-log regression model to estimate elasticity so you can see what is the percentage change on Y due to a 1% increase on X.

Comment: Please show us a simple example, including an expected output. This question can be interpreted in too many different ways at the moment.